# php check date if month is equal to something

Tags: php, date, datetime

So i fetched the date into MSSQL's datetime type field.

E.g `2014-01-23 06:54:49.647`

I need a simple way to determine if the datetime corresponds a specific month in a condition in PHP

```
//i wanted something like this
$getthedate = odbc_exec($connection, "SELECT date FROM sometable WHERE ..somecondition..");
$datedata =  odbc_result($getthedate, 'DATE');
if($datedata = /* is january */) {
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
$datedata = "2014-10-19 12:36:00";
if(strtolower(date('F',strtotime($datedata))) == strtolower(date('F'))){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "unsucess";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can convert the time to a UNIX timestamp by using strtotime:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($datedata); //2014-01-23 06:54:49.647 = 1390460089
```

Then convert the timestamp into whatever format you want with the 'date' function:

```
$month = date('F', $timestamp); // Outputs: January
```

Then you can use $month to compare in your if statement as it returns the month of the date.

```
if ($month == "January") {
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable containing the date time string

```
2014-01-23 06:54:49.647
```

and you know it'll be in that format, simply use http://php.net/substr to get the month.

(This ignores any time zone issues since you didn't mention that.)

Answer (score 1):

```
try this

<?php
$timestamp="2014-01-23 06:54:49.647";
$month = date('F', $timestamp);
$current_month=date('F');
if($month==$current_month)
{
//do something
}
?>
                                OR



<?php
    $timestamp="2014-01-23 06:54:49.647";
    $month = date('m', $timestamp);
    $current_month=date('m');
    if($month==$current_month)
    {
    //do something
    }
```